# Dust.js overwrites Knockout observables on render

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dust.js

I am using [Dust.js](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/) and [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/) together on a project, using a module called [Duster-KO](https://github.com/socialtables/duster-ko) to integrate the two. The problem happens when I am trying to render a dust template client-side: when I pass an observable, or any object containing an observable, to dust.render() in the Context parameter, Dust is actually setting the KO observable to be a "Chunk" object. I believe this is because Knockout observables are functions, and so Dust thinks that the function I am passing it is a callback instead of an observable, which it is then executing and somehow setting the observable that way.

Is there any way to avoid this issue, or otherwise prevent Dust from touching the observables?

Here is an example of a situation I have run into:

```
var guest = exports.guest = function(opts) {
  this.first = ko.observable(opts.first||"")
  this.last = ko.observable(opts.last||"")

  // ... more model code here
}

var table = exports.table = function(opts) {
  // This is an observable array of guest objects
  this.guests = ko.observableArray(opts.guests||[])
  this.template = "tableTemplate"
  this.target = opts.target  // This is whatever DOM element we are injecting the template into

  // ... more model code here

  var self = this

  this.draw = function() {
    // Before we render the Dust template, the guest's first and last name are as they should be

    // this.ctx is a Context object inherited from another parent object, which has the current object pushed onto it
    var rendered = dust.render(self.template, this.ctx)

    // At this point in the code, the guest's first and last name have been set to Chunk objects, rather than their actual first and last names

    self.target.appendChild(rendered)
  }
}
```

In the above example, before I render the dust template each guest's first and last names are intact and as they should be. However, afterwards they are changed to Chunk objects.

And before someone suggests it, removing Dust and using only Knockout is not an option right now unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Did u apply the hack mentioned in the Duster-Ko Readme file???

> Why the Dust hack :(
>
> Unpleasant business, that.
>
> Dust expects any functional tags to accept a set of parameters (chunk,
>   context). We could build a Dust-friendly wrapper for every KO
>   Observer, and build Dust contexts out of these, but that seems like an
>   awful lot of unnecessary object creation.
>
> Instead, we just hack Dust to not evaluate Observers like it normally
>   would, and handle the aftermath with a more stock standard
>   helper-filter.
>
> The Source
>
> These changes are done in whatever dust*js you're using.
>
> Prime hackery:
>
> ```
> Chunk.prototype.reference = function(elem, context, auto, filters) {
> -  if (typeof elem === "function") {
> +  if (typeof elem === "function" && elem.name != "observable") {
>      elem = elem(this, context, null, {auto: auto, filters: filters});`
> ```
>
> Oh, also, we're manually invoking some Dust templates & cough eval'ing
>   that. To manually invoke the template, we need to pass in a Dust Chunk
>   object, which normally we wouldn't be exposed to, so:
>
> ```
> +dust.chunk= Chunk Tis all! Checkout lib/dust-patch.js for a patch
> ```
>
> against unspecified Dust sources (for now, dust-core-0.3.0.js is the
>   intended target).